# How to expand ul and li in jquery manually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to expand li inside ul manually in jquery.

my HTML

```
<ul id="ui-id">
  <li>A</li>
<ul id="ui-id-inner1">
  <li>S</li>
  <li>T</li>
  <li>V</li>
</ul>
  <li>B</li>
<ul id="ui-id-inner2">
  <li>G</li>
  <li>H</li>
  <li>J</li>
</ul>
  <li>C</li>
<ul id="ui-id-inner3">
  <li>O</li>
  <li>P</li>
  <li>Q</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

//how to expand ul inside li manually

Comment: This is invalid HTML! You can't set `<ul>` directly inside `<ul>`, You need `<li>`!

Comment: Also show us what you tried so far.

Comment: show what you have tried so far????

Comment: you don't need jquery for this you can do it using pure css3, Also if you try using google, there are plenty of plugins / examples of how to do this using either jquery or css

Answer (score 0):

Something like this basic example should give you a good base to work from. If you want something a little more comprehensive, you can [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css%20hover%20menu&oq=css%20hover%20menu&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3039j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) for [other tutorials](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)

```css
ul, li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

ul ul { display: none; position: absolute; left: 5em; }

li { width: 5em; background-color: green; }

li:hover ul { display: block; }

li li { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<ul id="ui-id">
  <li>A
    <ul id="ui-id-inner1">
      <li>S</li>
      <li>T</li>
      <li>V</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>B
    <ul id="ui-id-inner2">
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li>
      <li>J</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>C
    <ul id="ui-id-inner3">
      <li>O</li>
      <li>P</li>
      <li>Q</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand what you want to achieve, but I suspect that this might be what you're looking for ?

Take a look at the source code - its mostly CSS.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/listview-collapsible-item-indented/